# Parsing extra lines in CSV file

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I have a csv file that has some additional lines in the header and the final line in the end, something like this:

```
!ReleaseDate:20131120
!id|AssetIDType|AssetID|StartDate|EndDate
ARGAAA1|CINS|P00879117|19860131|20090323
ARGAAA1|CUSIP|P00879117|19860131|20090323
......
ZIMADQ1|SEDOL|B7W9VC2|20121008|20751231
[End of File]
```

I want to parse it using Text::CSV_XS .

1. Is there a way to get rid of first line? (I guess I could just skip it)
2. Take second line as column names (skip the first "!")
3. Read until I get the [End of File], this is a string, not EOF symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, sep_char => '|' } );

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", 'File.csv' or die "File.csv: $!";

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    next if $row->[0] =~ /^!|\[/;
    print $row->[2], "\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Output on your dataset:

```
P00879117
P00879117
B7W9VC2
```

This gets the `next` line if the current one begins with a character (or set of characters) you wouldn't find in the first column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this does most of what I asked, it doesn't read the column names automatically though (2nd question).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get rid of first line? (I guess I could just skip it)

Looks like you might check for lines starting with `!`, or just skip the first line if you're pretty confident in the file format.

> Take second line as column names (skip the first !)

You could read the header line with [`getline`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#getline), then pass the resulting arrayref to [`column_names`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#column_names) before reading the rest of the file with [`getline_hr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#getline_hr). The module's documentation offers an example something like this:

```
my @cols = @{$csv->getline($io)};
$csv->column_names(@cols);
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($io)) {
    print $row->{price}; #this assumes there is a 'price' field
}
```

If you're going to read in a *lot* of data, you can optimize with [`bind_columns`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#bind_columns), again using examples from the module's documentation.

> Read until I get the [End of File]?

As seen in the code snippet above, a `while` loop will do the trick. The various getline functions will return undef or some other false value once you've reached the end of the file, which will terminate the loop.

Comment: [End of File] is not EOF symbol, it's a string. And the second line has "!" sign in front of it, so bind_columns will probably take it as a part of the name

Comment: @RomanHoyenko You can **easily** adapt rutter's code for your task. To strip the leading `!` from the column names, update `@cols` before calling `$csv->column_names(@cols)`. And you can check for your magic `[End of File]` string inside the while loop and exit the loop if you hit it.

Comment: I thought $csv->getline_hr($io) would fail on getting the [End of File]. I want it to fail on non-correct rows, but not on this line.

Comment: @RomanHoyenko Did you even try it? I get `[End of File]` as the value for the first column and all other columns are `undef`.